# Do uniform lattices in simple lie groups contain free abelian subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a cocompact lattice in a simple Lie group $G$ such that $G$ has rank at least $2$. Does $\Gamma$ contain a rank $2$ free abelian group?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  You should update your question with information about what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, in fact, also holds for all lattices in all noncompact connected semisimple Lie groups $G$: Every such lattice $\Gamma$ is Zariski dense (this is due to Borel) and, hence, is not virtually solvable. Now, using Tits' Alternative, conclude that $\Gamma$ contains $Z * Z$.

As for free abelian subgroups of rank 2, again, all lattices in semisimple Lie groups of rank $\ge 2$ (uniform and not) contain $Z^2$: Theorem 2.8 in

G. Prasad, M. Raghunathan, Cartan subgroups and lattices in semi-simple groups. Ann. of Math. (2) 96 (1972), 296–317.

Comment: The question asked about free abelian subgroups instead of free subgroups.

Comment: @DavidCohen: I see. The answer is the same: all higher rank lattices contain $Z^2$.